# Find all solutions to $2^n+n=m!$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all natural $m,n$ such that:

$$2^n+n=m!$$

I think the first $m$ factors to be discussed.

Comment: This question would be better received if you wrote about your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** How many factors 2 does $m!$ have?

Is it for large $m$ possible that $2^n+n$ has the same number of factors 2 as $m!$?

Comment: $2^{2^k}+2^k$ has $k$ factors of $2$, so for any $m$ we can arrange for $2^n+n$ to have the same number of factors of $2$ as $m!$. We could probably use Stirling's approximation to see that if $2^n+n$ and $m!$ have the same number of factors of $2$, then $2^n+n\gg m!$.

Comment: @JulianRosen That is exactly the point of the hint.

Comment: @JulianRosen not that easy to do what you are saying

Comment: @EugenCovaci Why not? Clearly $m!$ has at least $m/2$ factors 2, so $n\geq m/2$. It is not hard to proof that $$2^{2^{m/2}}+2^{m/2} > m!$$ for $m$ sufficiently large.